# PyTorch: apply mask with different shape

Tags: pytorch

I have a tensor of shape `(60, 3, 32, 32)` and a boolean mask of shape `(60, 32, 32)`. I want to apply this mask to the tensor. The output tensor should have shape `(60, 3, 32, 32)`, and values are kept if the mask is 1, else 0.
How can I do that fast?

Comment: Is it a boolean mask that you want to use to filter values from the tensor?

Comment: Yes it is a boolean mask.

Comment: What is the expected output? Same shape as the original tensor with zeroes where the mask is false, or a smaller tensor with only values where the mask is true?

Comment: Yes, the former: output has same shape as the input tensor, keep values where the mask is 1 and 0 elsewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let `t` be the tensor and `m` be the mask. You can use:

```
t * m.unsqueeze(1)
```